# Sqlite running update in insert trigger to execute update trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, insert, sql-update

Using sqlite I want to have a field 'url' generated from the given 'id' using a trigger both on insert and on update. For example `id: '1' => url: 'test.com/1'`

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id TEXT,
  url TEXT
 );
```

Since sqlite can't run the same trigger for update and insert, I see two options to accomplish this.

**Option A**

- run a trigger after insert, that updates the id to itself, which in turns triggers the update trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER run_updates_on_insert AFTER INSERT ON t1
  BEGIN
    UPDATE t1 SET id = NEW.id WHERE id = NEW.id;
  END;

CREATE TRIGGER set_url_on_update BEFORE UPDATE on t1
  BEGIN
   UPDATE t1 SET url = 'test.com/' || NEW.id WHERE id = OLD.id;
  END;
```

**Option B**

- replicating the logic in two separate triggers for update and insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_url_on_insert AFTER INSERT on t1
  BEGIN
   UPDATE t1 SET url = 'test.com/' || NEW.id WHERE id = NEW.id;
  END;

CREATE TRIGGER set_url_on_update BEFORE UPDATE on t1
  BEGIN
   UPDATE t1 SET url = 'test.com/' || NEW.id WHERE id = OLD.id;
  END;
```

Both of these options give me the desired results, I tend to favor Option A, as I only have to write the update logic once, but I was wondering if there are any other advantages/disadvantage to prefer one to the other?

EDIT: For this particular use case it is better to use generated column (see forpas answer below)

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: Sqlite Version: 3.36.0

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.31.0 (2020-01-22) of SQLite, you can create [generated columns](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) (stored or virtual), so you don't need any triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id TEXT,
  url TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ('test.com/' || id) STORED
 );
```

Comment: Thank you, that does solve my particular problem! However in case somebody else comes across the question, I'm not gonna mark it as the correct answer, as it is more of a workaround and the question of how to best combine insert with update triggers, probably could be useful outside of this scenario.

Comment: @react-newbie every new feature introduced in a programming language or dialect is not a workaround but a solution to common problems for which other workarounds were used to solve them. An insert trigger that fires an update trigger is a workaround. An insert trigger and an update trigger that execute the same code was a solution but not any more. So, when it comes to chose between a workaround, an old solution and the new proper solution the choice is obvious.

Comment: Sure, I'm not questioning the usefulness of your suggestion, and I actually will use it that way. But let's say somebody else finds the question and he wants to run a trigger on update and insert, that creates a log entry in a different table. In his case, the answer wouldn't help him.

Comment: @react-newbie when others search for "triggers" they will find hundreds of threads. If they are looking for "how to creates a log entry in a different table" then they will pass because the requirement is different. Your question is about creating a calculated column and what you tried was triggers, which works. My answer is about something new and better. Did you expect me to suggest Option A or Option B? Both options are obsolete.